# Ionic hybrid app - unable to change background color of button when certain condition met

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using `ionic` to build a hybrid app. I'm also using `ionicons`. I'm trying to change the background color of a button when a certain condition is met.
 This works:

```
<i class="icon ion-checkmark" ng-class="{active: item.status=='true'}"></i>
```

I'm able to change the color of the icon itself.

However, this does not:

```
 <ion-option-button class="button-energized" ng-click="foo(item)" ng-class="{back: item.status=='true'}"></ion-option-button>
```

I'm not able to change the background color of the button, it stays yellow.
CSS I used:

```
.active{
    color:red;
}

.back{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Full code available in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5goe3wL/).

For the sake of the example, the "condition" is just an alternating boolean value which changes once the button is clicked.

EDIT:
This works if I add `important` as follows:

```
.back{
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Is there a better or more correct way to achieve this?

Comment: can't see the icons in the fiddle

Comment: You have to swipe the cell to the left in order to reveal the icons.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know (and am using it the same way) this is perfectly fine (by using the `!important` CSS rule).